# KQL group by or summarize count by see the rest of the columns

Tags: kql, askql

I would like to ask your help with a kql query:

```
DeviceEvents 
| distinct InitiatingProcessAccountUpn,DeviceName,DeviceId
| join DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities on $left.DeviceId == $right.DeviceId
| summarize count() by SoftwareName, DeviceId
```

The problem is I used summarize count by there are many software versions and I just want to see the version of the software from each machine, and it did the tick but I can not re-add the missing columns from the table.

I tried to rejoin with the same table but wasn't successfull.

What I would like to see is from one machine one software.
Now, if I have this, I can see the name of the software and ID but I want to see in the final report the rest column as well.

Do you have any idea what I can do better?
Thanks

Comment: it's a bit difficult to understand what you want to achieve here.
can you provide an example input and the required output for that example input?
best would be to provide them with the datatable operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use take_any:

```
summarize take_any(SomeOtherColumns)
```

Or you could add the other column as a grouping key and then do another summarize and aggregate it somehow (also take_any(), max(), arg_max(), make_list() etc)